# How to post on instagram from Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, instagram

I followed these steps:

```
 sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Next, install the chromeos-apk tool:

```
 sudo npm install chromeos-apk -g
```

Make a directory in your home folder

```
 mkdir apks
```

then download runtime library from this link [Archon], extract it into the apks directory. I used 32-bit Archon

Open your Chrome or Chromium browser version number is higher than 38, then **Chrome > "Hamburger" menu > Tools > Extensions**, click **Enable developer mode**, and use the <kbd>Load unpacked extension</kbd> button to load the Archon runtime library.

Then I downloaded the Instagram_10.17.0_apk-dl.com.apk file from http://apk-dl.com/

And then I ran:

```
chromeos-apk Instagram_10.17.0_apk-dl.com.apk --tablet
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
Failed to load APK
Failed to parse package name in the APK.
Unknown APK package.
Please enter the package name (i.e "com.skype.raider", if you get this    wrong your app will NOT work):
```

Answer (score 0):

`chromeos-apk` expects the package name, not the filename. Try `chromeos-apk com.instagram.android.apk --tablet`.

Source: https://github.com/vladikoff/chromeos-apk

Comment: The link says "Run chromeos-apk [path to apk file]". So it expects the filename.

Comment: Withe the example of "chromeos-apk com.soundcloud.android.apk"

Comment: The filename need not be the package name. `com.soundcloud.android.apk` is the name of the apk file. It works even if you name it something else.

Comment: "If you get a Failed to parse package name in the APK. error, then you will have to type it the proper package name for the application. You can find out the package name by looking at the URL of the app in the Play Store."